Issue with AUTH0 and NextJS
I am making a side project using nextjs and wanted to add auth0. I have it working to the point where I am able to login, however, upon redirect I get the following error. How do i fix this?
This site can’t provide a secure connectionlocalhost sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
I have tried configuring the callback url to be http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback in the auth0 dashboard

can you share the github repo

what is the auth npm package you are using

Im using the deafult npm auth0 package -- npm install @auth0/nextjs-auth0

Perhaps your browser is redirecting to https? Try clearing site data, this usually makes the browser try http again instead of https

I followed the documentation mentioned on the app creation page.
Can you please cross-check the configuration with my app?
In your app settings.




I guess the issue is with the CORS URL for the allowed web origins in your configuration
